# What's the meaning of using patterns in Django URLs?

Tags: django, django-urls

In my Django project, I find the project urls.py resolve URLs directly

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^test/', include('test.urls')),
]
```

but I find the app urls.py solution always use

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^new$', views.new, name='new'),
)
```

when I try to change app's urls.py to

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^new$', views.new, name='new'),
]
```

or

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
)
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^new$', views.new, name='new'),
)
```

also works, so I want to know the meaning of using patterns and which one is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Patterns` is deprecated since 1.8 (and removed in 1.10)

from [the 1.8 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urls/#patterns):

> Deprecated since version 1.8:
>
> urlpatterns should be a plain list of django.conf.urls.url() instances instead.